# Pause functions on page history forward backward

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

There is `Home.vue` and `Statistics.vue` pages. `Home.vue` render the `TableFields.vue` component. At `Home.vue` there are fields numbers with initial value "3" set on page load. Set interval on calculate function adds numbers every two seconds. How to achieve, that when going from '/' to '/statistics' all the changing should be paused, and on returning back it should be resumed? Bellow each field at home page, already there are buttons that toggle `setInterval()` function and stop/resume calculations. Basically, when going from "/" to "/statistics" `clearInterval()` should be triggered that stops the calculations at "/" page. @Saksham TableFields.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table class="table-a">
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <td class="sign">{{ this.randomSign.A }}</td>
        <td>{{ initialValue.A }}</td>
        <td v-show="this.randomSign.A == '+'">&#x2B06;</td>
        <td v-show="this.randomSign.A == '-'">&#x2B07;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button @click="toggleIntervalA()">
      <span v-show="this.startStop.A">Stop</span>
      <span v-show="!this.startStop.A">Start</span>
    </button>
    <table class="table-b">
      <tr>
        <th>B</th>
        <td class="sign">{{ this.randomSign.B }}</td>
        <td>{{ initialValue.B }}</td>
        <td v-show="this.randomSign.B == '+'">&#x2B06;</td>
        <td v-show="this.randomSign.B == '-'">&#x2B07;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button @click="toggleIntervalB()">
      <span v-show="this.startStop.B">Stop</span>
      <span v-show="!this.startStop.B">Start</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'TableFields',
  props: {
    changesA: {
      type: Array,
      required: false
    },
    changesB: {
      type: Array,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fields: ['A', 'B'],
      startStop: {
        A: true,
        B: true
      },
      initialValue: {
        A: 3,
        B: 3
      },
      randomNumbersArray: [],
      randomSign: {
        A: '+',
        B: '+'
      },
      signsArray: ['+', '-'],
      interval: {
        A: null,
        B: null
      },
      localChanges: {
        A: [],
        B: []
      },
      timer: undefined
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    firstObjects () {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
        const date = new Date()
        const obj = {}
        obj.field = this.fields[i]
        obj.value = Number((Math.random() * 1 + 1).toFixed(2))
        obj.time = date.toLocaleTimeString()
        this.changesA.push(obj[0])
        this.changesB.push(obj[1])
        this.$emit('update:changesA', this.localChanges.A)
        this.$emit('update:changesB', this.localChanges.B)
      }
    },
    replaceNumbersArray () { // replace random A, B numbers at time interval
      const n1 = Number((Math.random() * 1 + 1).toFixed(2)) // n1 = first number (A)
      const n2 = Number((Math.random() * 1 + 1).toFixed(2)) // n2 = second number (B)
      this.randomNumbersArray.splice(0, 2, n1, n2)
    },
    toggleIntervalA () {
      this.startStop.A = !this.startStop.A
      if (this.startStop.A) {
        this.interval.A = setInterval(this.calculationsA, 2000)
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval.A)
      }
    },
    toggleIntervalB () {
      this.startStop.B = !this.startStop.B
      if (this.startStop.B) {
        this.interval.B = setInterval(this.calculationsB, 2000)
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval.B)
      }
    },
    calculationsA () {
      this.randomSign.A = this.signsArray[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.signsArray.length)
      ]
      this.randomSign.A === '+'
        ? (this.initialValue.A += this.randomNumbersArray[0])
        : (this.initialValue.A -= this.randomNumbersArray[0])
      const date = new Date()
      const newChange = {}
      newChange.field = 'A'
      newChange.value = this.randomNumbersArray[0]
      newChange.time = date.toLocaleTimeString()
      this.changesA.push(newChange)
      this.$emit('update:changesA', this.localChanges.A)
    },
    calculationsB () {
      this.randomSign.B = this.signsArray[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.signsArray.length)
      ]
      this.randomSign.B === '+'
        ? (this.initialValue.B += this.randomNumbersArray[1])
        : (this.initialValue.B -= this.randomNumbersArray[1])
      const date = new Date()
      const newChange = {}
      newChange.field = 'B'
      newChange.value = this.randomNumbersArray[1]
      newChange.time = date.toLocaleTimeString()
      this.changesB.push(newChange)
      this.$emit('update:changesB', this.localChanges.B)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.firstObjects()
    setInterval(this.replaceNumbersArray, 2000)
    this.initialValue.A = this.$root.initialValue.A || 3
    this.initialValue.B = this.$root.initialValue.B || 3
    this.timer = setInterval(_ => {
      this.interval.A = this.calculationsA
      this.interval.B = this.calculationsB
    }, 2000)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    this.$root.initialValue.A = this.initialValue.A
    this.$root.initialValue.B = this.initialValue.B
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.table-b {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.sign {
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding: 5px 10px;

  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
</style>
```

Project repo: [link](https://gitlab.com/srdjan-milic/factory-worldwide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `beforeDestroy()` hook to push the counter to either the root component or to vuex store (if you are using one) and fetch the counter in the `mounted()` hook once you return to the route to resume from there.

and use in your component as

```
export default {
...
    beforeDestroy () {
        this.$root.counter = this.counter;
    },
    mounted () {
        this.counter = this.$root.counter || 0;
    }
...
}
```

I have created a sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/preserve-timer-state-2osi7 which preserves the state of timer when we move out of the route and starts the timer from where we left.

**Comment Notes:**

As per you comment, it seems that you are trying to set a property to an object which is undefined. Initially there is no property by the name `initialValue` in the root component and you are trying to access a property `A` inside it.

You need to first check if `initialValue` is defined and then try to check for `A`

```
this.initialValue.A = this.$root.initialValue && this.$root.initialValue.A ?  this.$root.initialValue.A : 3
```

Also make sure your data has `initialValue` as an empty object

```
initialValue: {}
```

Comment: TableFields.vue;  
`import EventBus from '../event-bus'`  
...  
  `beforeDestroy () {
    EventBus.$emit('Store_Counter', payLoad)
  },`  

  `mounted () {
    this.firstObjects()
    setInterval(this.replaceNumbersArray, 2000)
    EventBus.$on('Store_Counter', function (payLoad) {
      this.interval.A = setInterval(this.calculationsA, 2000)
      this.interval.B = setInterval(this.calculationsB, 2000)
    })
  }`

It complains that `payLoad` at `beforeDestroy ()` is not defined, and can't compile...

Comment: let me post a sample sandbox @SrdjanMilic

Comment: @SrdjanMilic check the sample i created.

Comment: I'm working to implement solution you have provided since you have post the sample. I will get back to you after I do all I can to make it work.

Comment: Your sample is pretty straightforward, but I am struggling to implement it at my component. I need to have few(10) independent fields with interval that calculates random numbers. I have implemented two in the code for now.  Please take a look at edited question, I've pasted component code with attempt based on your sample.  
1. there is `this.$root.initialValue is undefined` error in `this.initialValue.A = this.$root.initialValue.A || 3`  as `initialValue.A` is object property.  
2. I don't know is my implementation according to your sample is correct as well

Comment: there is repo link bellow the question if you might not see it. Also I can refactor the code if necessary..

Comment: As I understand, you suggest that I change this line `this.initialValue.A = this.$root.initialValue.A || 3` with one you have provided in "Comment Notes".  
Also, where I should define `initialValue: {}`. TableFields.vue component from above already has properties A, B defined  for `initialValue` object. Do you mean to define it in App.vue?

Comment: I have changed object to an array, and tweak the code according to your first proposal and it's worked. Thank you very much, anyway.

Comment: I've up-voted. Please, if you don't find annoying, could you check this  [link go question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278814/resume-adding-rows-on-history-back-and-forward/61285177#61285177). It's related to this one. I've tried to implement same approach but without successes.