# Resume adding rows on history back and forward

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

There is two pages: `Home.vue` and `Statistics.vue`. At home page, there is the interval that counts some numbers at page load. When you switch to "/statistic" page interval is stopped and when you get back to "/" page, interval and counting are start from when they stopped. Problem is, that I need to resume adding rows to "/statistic" page once when you switch from "/statistics" to "/" and back again to "/statistics". Now "/statistics" always reset values to default and start adding rows from beginning. Working code example to check solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-sound-rseqb

"/statistics" page:

```
<template>
  <div class="statistics">
    <table v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
      <tr>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(change, index) in changesArray[index]" :key="index">
        <td>{{ change.field }}</td>
        <td>{{ change.value }}</td>
        <td>{{ change.time }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Statistics',
  props: {
    changesA: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    changesB: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fields: ['A', 'B'],
      changesArray: [this.changesA, this.changesB]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.statistics {
  display: flex;
}
table:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
```

"App.vue"

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/statistics">Statistics</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view :changesA.sync="changesA" :changesB.sync="changesB" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      changesA: [],
      changesB: []
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px 0;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of changes done by me to fix your code

Firstly, you were trying to pass `localChanges` to parent which is getting initialized on each component load which is resetting your array. It is fixed by using

```
this.changesA.push({ ...obj });
this.changesB.push({ ...obj });
this.$emit("update:changesA", [...this.changesA]);
this.$emit("update:changesB", [...this.changesB]);
```

Secondly, in your `firstObjects()` method, you were pushing an item at index on `obj` as

```
this.changesB.push({ ...obj[i] }); //see i
```

which is wrong

Also, I think you want to call `firstObjects()` only if the array is empty which can be done by simply putting an enclosing condition.

Fixed sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/live-stats-with-pause-on-route-change-lqmqo

Comment: In your sandbox example  statistics logs are a bit messy, although your fixes are the right ones. I wasn't sure what did you exactly mean by suggestion about `firstObjects()`, but that has inspired me to write at mounted hook block:  
`if (this.changesA && this.changesB === []) {
      this.firstObjects()
    }`   
 and voila!!! Everything is working perfectly. now. :)

Comment: And man, i can't thank you enough for your unselfish help. Best regards to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is the keep-alive; as shown in Vue documentation.

```
<keep-alive>
  <component v-bind:is="statistics"></component>
</keep-alive>
```

Vue Documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Could you please test that code at "code sandbox" . Link is at the end of the question. If it's working, please write exactly how to implement it, as I have tried without success.

Comment: That approach can't work as in that case `change` variable in for loop always expect values from "/" page. When you click back to "/" there is an error `change is undefined` which brakes the page. I have tried `<keep-alive include="statistics">` at `<router-view :changesA.sync="changesA" :changesB.sync="changesB" />`.